# Android app shows behind the home screen,why?

Tags: android

Android app shows behind the home screen,why?

Like this:

[image]

Android style AppTheme with Mainfest.
maybe the problem is caused by this style.

```html
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/actionbar</item>

        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/darker_gray</item>

        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>

        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar</item>

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/white</item>

        <item name="android:textColor">@color/font_color</item>

        <item name="android:editTextStyle">@style/AppTheme.EditText</item>

        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>

        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Post your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: AndroidManifest.xml is not special .Maybe the problem is caused by this style.(style is posting into the question)

Comment: remove  <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>

Comment: Thanks, it's useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove This line from your style.

```
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
```